# Why Look and feel is not getting updated properly?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I’m developing a swing application in which I have an option to change the Look and feel of the application on click of a button. Now my problem is when I click the button to change the theme it’s not properly updating the L&F of my app, say my previous theme is “noire” and I choose “MCWin” after it, but the style of the noire theme is still there

Here is sample working code:

```
package whiteboard;

    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants;



    public class DiscussionBoard extends JFrame implements ComponentListener,ActionListener {   

        // Variables declaration
        private JMenuItem audioMenuItem;
        private JMenuItem boardMenuItem;
        private JMenuItem exitMenuItem;
        private JMenuItem clientsMenuItem;
        private JMenuItem acryl;
        private JMenuItem hifi;
        private JMenuItem aero;
        private JMenuItem aluminium;
        private JMenuItem bernstein;
        private JMenuItem   fast;
        private JMenuItem graphite;
        private JMenuItem luna;
        private JMenuItem mcwin;

        private JMenuItem noire;
        private JMenuItem smart;
        private JMenuBar boardMenuBar;

        private JMenuItem messengerMenuItem;
        private JMenu openMenu;
        private JMenu saveMenu;
        private JMenu themesMenu;
        private JMenuItem saveMessengerMenuItem;
        private JMenuItem saveWhiteboardMenuItem;
        private JMenu userMenu;


        JLayeredPane layerpane; 


        /** Creates new form discussionBoard 
         * @param connection */
        public DiscussionBoard() 
        {       

            initComponents();   
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            addComponentListener(this);

        }

        private void initComponents() {

            boardMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
            openMenu = new JMenu();
            themesMenu = new JMenu();
            messengerMenuItem = new JMenuItem();
            boardMenuItem = new JMenuItem();
            audioMenuItem = new JMenuItem();
            saveMenu = new JMenu();
            saveMessengerMenuItem = new JMenuItem();
            saveWhiteboardMenuItem = new JMenuItem();
            userMenu = new JMenu();
            clientsMenuItem = new JMenuItem();
            exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setResizable(false);
            setTitle("Discussion Board");

            openMenu.setText("Open");
            saveMenu.setText("Save");
            themesMenu.setText("Themes");
            acryl = new JMenuItem("Acryl");
            hifi = new JMenuItem("HiFi");
            aero = new JMenuItem("Aero");
            aluminium = new JMenuItem("Aluminium");
            bernstein = new JMenuItem("Bernstein");
            fast = new JMenuItem("Fast");
            graphite = new JMenuItem("Graphite");
            luna = new JMenuItem("Luna");
            mcwin = new JMenuItem("MCwin");     
            noire = new JMenuItem("Noire");
            smart = new JMenuItem("Smart");


            hifi.addActionListener(this);
            acryl.addActionListener(this);
            aero.addActionListener(this);
            aluminium.addActionListener(this);
            bernstein.addActionListener(this);
            fast.addActionListener(this);
            graphite.addActionListener(this);
            luna.addActionListener(this);
            mcwin.addActionListener(this);      
            noire.addActionListener(this);
            smart.addActionListener(this);

            messengerMenuItem.setText("Messenger");     
            openMenu.add(messengerMenuItem);        
            openMenu.add(boardMenuItem);
            audioMenuItem.setText("Audio Messenger");
            openMenu.add(audioMenuItem);
            exitMenuItem.setText("Exit");
            exitMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    exitMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
            openMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

            boardMenuBar.add(openMenu);     

            saveMessengerMenuItem.setText("Messenger");

            saveMenu.add(saveMessengerMenuItem);

            saveWhiteboardMenuItem.setText("Whiteboard");       

            saveMenu.add(saveWhiteboardMenuItem);

            boardMenuBar.add(saveMenu);

            userMenu.setText("Users");
            clientsMenuItem.setText("Current Session");

            userMenu.add(clientsMenuItem);      
            themesMenu.add(acryl);
            themesMenu.add(hifi);       
            themesMenu.add(aero);
            themesMenu.add(aluminium);
            themesMenu.add(bernstein);
            themesMenu.add(fast);
            themesMenu.add(graphite);
            themesMenu.add(luna);
            themesMenu.add(mcwin);      
            themesMenu.add(noire);
            themesMenu.add(smart);
            boardMenuBar.add(userMenu);
            boardMenuBar.add(themesMenu);
            saveMessengerMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
            saveWhiteboardMenuItem.setEnabled(false);

            setJMenuBar(boardMenuBar);
            setSize(1024, 740);     
            setVisible(true);
        }

        protected void exitMenuItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.exit(0);     
        }
        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            try 
            {

                if(e.getSource()==hifi)
                {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
                        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel");
                        enableTheme();
                        hifi.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(e.getSource()==acryl)
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.acryl.AcrylLookAndFeel");
                    enableTheme();
                    acryl.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(e.getSource()==aero)
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aero.AeroLookAndFeel");
                    enableTheme();
                    aero.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(e.getSource()==aluminium)
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.aluminium.AluminiumLookAndFeel");
                    enableTheme();
                    aluminium.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(e.getSource()==bernstein)
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.bernstein.BernsteinLookAndFeel");
                    enableTheme();
                    bernstein.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(e.getSource()==fast)
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.fast.FastLookAndFeel");
                    enableTheme();
                    fast.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(e.getSource()==graphite)
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.graphite.GraphiteLookAndFeel");
                    enableTheme();
                    graphite.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(e.getSource()==luna)
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.luna.LunaLookAndFeel");
                    enableTheme();
                    luna.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(e.getSource()==mcwin)
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.mcwin.McWinLookAndFeel");
                    enableTheme();
                    mcwin.setEnabled(false);
                }

                else if(e.getSource()==noire)
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.noire.NoireLookAndFeel");
                    enableTheme();
                    noire.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if(e.getSource()==smart)
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.smart.SmartLookAndFeel");
                    enableTheme();
                    smart.setEnabled(false);
                }
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());    
            }  
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private void enableTheme()
        {
            acryl.setEnabled(true);
            hifi.setEnabled(true);      
            aero.setEnabled(true);
            aluminium.setEnabled(true);
            bernstein.setEnabled(true);
            fast.setEnabled(true);
            graphite.setEnabled(true);
            luna.setEnabled(true);
            mcwin.setEnabled(true);     
            noire.setEnabled(true);
            smart.setEnabled(true);
        }

        public static void main(String []ar)
        {
            try 
            {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.acryl.AcrylLookAndFeel");            
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {           
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            new DiscussionBoard();
        }
    }
```

What’s the problem here? why its not getting updated?

There is a demo application [here](http://www.jtattoo.net/Download.html) which is exactly doing what i want but i cant get a clear idea of it.

**`Edit:`** Sorry, forgot to specify the library file, [here](http://www.jtattoo.net/downloads/JTattooDemo.jar) it is

Comment: You are using third party L&Fs (`com.jtattoo`). Are they in your classpath, or are you getting a `ClassNotFoundException` when you try to switch LookAndFeels?

Comment: sorry peter, i forgot to specify the library file link.

u can find it here
http://www.jtattoo.net/downloads/JTattooDemo.jar

Comment: Just a side note: I'd clean up those else-if clauses by factoring out a common method. Parameters could be a constant for the L&F name and a JMenuItem

Comment: Any idea guyz??? peter??

Comment: got the answer--> for jtattoo theme before applying the new theme we need to reset the theme to a default theme, which can be done by """com.jtattoo.plaf.aero.AeroLookAndFeel.setTheme("Default");"""

this works fine

Comment: Thanx for all your replies :)

Answer (score 1):

Move the `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(getRootPane());` call to after the calls that set up the LnF. It calls `updateUI` on all components in the tree below the passed component. Right now, you are updating the UIs then changing them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing this, but have you had a look at the [updateUI-method](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html#updateUI%28%29)?

From the API docs:

> Resets the UI property with a value from the current look and feel.

Comment: I'm not sure what it does exactly. I just spotted the connection between the description in the API, your problem, and that the call was missing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and it just worked fine:

[image]

---

I tried it from commandline with the following files (`DiscussionBoard.java` in the directory `whiteboard`):

```
JTattooDemo.jar
whiteboard/DiscussionBoard.java
```

```
javac whiteboard/DiscussionBoard.java
java -cp ".;JTattooDemo.jar" whiteboard/DiscussionBoard
```

---

Note that the [JTattoo](http://www.jtattoo.net/Purchase.html) is only free *for non commercial use*.

Comment: it wont show you any error, but the problem is it wont update the theme properly, try selecting the theme randomly, atleast 10 themes, it will not look how it is supposed to be. see the screenshots in the following link
http://www.jtattoo.net/ScreenShots.html

Comment: Ya peter i am not using the theme for commercial app

Comment: @swift: I tried to change L&F with your provided code at least 30 times, and everything seems to change as expected (the title-bar, the icons and the menu)...